# Bad flag parameter or structure field unrecognized or unsupported array type in cvgetmat

Tags: java, opencv

*The question title seems to be duplicated, I agree with this, but the situation is not the same. So I did not find the solution for me.*

I get the error when I am trying to assign the Mat to `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` or `BackgroundSubtractorKNN`.

**The execution flow is like this:**

- Get the byte array of JPEG image via TCP Socket. *No problem*
- Convert the byte array to Mat as code below. *No problem*

  `Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(sJpegPicBuffer), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);`
- If needed to convert to gray-scale, also can be converted
  successfully. *No problem*
- Covert the Mat to BufferedImage. *No problem*
- Then display the BufferedImage in a JPanel. *No problem*

**But**
When assign it to the `BackgroundSubtractor` here the problem happened. *Problem*

```
subtractor.apply(mat, foregroundImg , -1);
```

**Note:**
I am using OpenCV 3.0 in Java. When I use webcam or read video file and go the same flow no problem happen, it goes very well.

Now what can be the reason for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a positive learning rate (the last parameter for the `apply()` method).

Try some small value like 0.01.

**Edit:**

Just noticed that -1 is the default and is internally converted to a value `>= 0`.

Comment: If it is the problem of -1, than why webcam and video file works well. Negative parameter value makes the algorithm to use some automatically chosen learning rate (0~1), so it seems that is not the problem of learn rate.

Comment: Is perhaps `mat` or `foregroundImg` empty and of the correct type? How do you test it when you're not using a webcam or video file?

Comment: foregroundImg is not empty, I check the type of both of them was the same (16), and I print out the every channel of both of them and it was the same ([136.0, 136.0, 136.0] ... more) and also the same depth (0). Now I also don't why it not work. What will be the reason.

Comment: I believe `foregroundImg` must be single channel image mask [see docs](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/df6/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractor.html#aa735e76f7069b3fa9c3f32395f9ccd21). Code 16 seems to correspond to CV_8UC3.

Comment: No no, foregroundImg is returned by this apply() function, it is the result, so the type and others the function itself determine not we, yes it return a binary image, I really does't why it not work, but it works with webcam or video file, while the mat of all of them are the same same. Anyway thanks for you response, by the way if you have any idea can tell me to solve this.

Comment: Yes I understand that it is returned, but it shouldn't be type 16 then right? I expect it to be type 0 (or CV_8UC1).